# Fatal error after PHP version upgrade

Tags: php, iis, fatal-error, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I just upgraded my PHP version after reinstalling the server. A code which worked previously doesn't work anymore. It tells me about a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: in J:\web\intranet\dologin.php on line 40
```

I checked the lines near that (39-41 are included below) and I can't see anything which could be wrong.

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user = ? AND password = ?");
$query->execute(array($user, $password));

$result = $query->fetch();
```

I'm running PHP 5.4.9 on Windows Server 2012. In php.ini I've set error reporting to show all the errors and I have also enabled PDO extension.

What's wrong?

Comment: You have display_errors on, but what's your error_reporting level? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: It has been set to E_ALL in php.ini.

Comment: There is no additional info regarding the fatal error?